# Selecting variable for dynamically created column MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a table and script that is dynamically altered when necessary.

So at rare points in time a table column is needed as it doesn't exist. It is then added to the end of the table. Something like below:

```
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ +----+------+------+------------------+-------------------+ ║
╠═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ | id | Col2 | Col3 | dynamicallyadded | dynamicallyadded2 | ║
║ +----+------+------+------------------+-------------------+ ║
║ |  1 |   33 |    3 |                3 |                 3 | ║
║ |  2 |   44 |    4 |                1 |                 1 | ║
║ |  3 |   45 |   23 |              533 |               533 | ║
║ +----+------+------+------------------+-------------------+ ║
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

So dynamicallyadded column is added.

Now, if I want to select the columns I can't figure out how to dynamically generate variables for the column information as briefly described below(remember these dynamic columns are created in the background):

```
$selectVar = Select statement when id = '1';
$dynamic1 = $selectVar ->dynamicallyadded;
$dynamic2 = $selectVar ->dynamicallyadded2;

echo '$dynamic1 and $dynamic2';
```

So when I spit this out as a report I'd like to be able to spit out the report of each dynamic column though I won't know what the column names are after id.

I've been fiddling with counting columns, but I'm not sure this is a great route. Any better ideas

Comment: You can use `SELECT *` and then `fetch_assoc()` will return an associative array with all the column names as keys. You can then loop through that to get all the columns.

Answer (score 0):

`DESCRIBE my_table;`

or

`SHOW COLUMNS FROM table;`

or

`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table';`

Comment: Hi Gavin. How could this be applied to generating variables though? I'm confused as to that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully. I thought you just needed the column names of a table if the column names weren't known.

Comment: Fetching the result as an associative array would have the column names as the key name.

Comment: Using one of the above methods you could build an array of column names and loop through the array.